# Is it possible to deploy WINDEV built on Windows OS into Linux OS?

Tags: windev

I have my WINDEV application built for windows OS.
Can it be made to run on Linux OS ?

(just like how Java's bytecode can run on any platform ? or like dotnet core can run on both windows and Linux )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to install WINE (windows on linux) to make the windows WINDEV Run on Linux.
Also we may need to modify the functions for Linux , since the functions sometimes will be specific to windows

Answer (score 1):

Hi you'll have to create a configuration for linux in your project. You can switch between these two configuration to compile for Windows or Linux.
Some part of your coe might work only for Windows and others for Linux.
Link to how to create a config : https://doc.windev.com/en-US/?9000114&name=
Can only work on
Ubuntu :    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Dedian : Debian 8.11
OpenSUSE:   OpenSUSE Leap 15.0
CentOS: CentOS 7.7